# Template: get proper variable name from type name

Tags: c++, templates

Let's say, I have 4 arrays of 4 different pointer types.
And I want a template function, which stores it's argument in the proper array. Something like this

```
int*            arr_int[10];
double*         arr_double[10];
uint64_t*       arr_uint64_t[10];


template <typename T> 
void add_value (int pos, T value) {
        //i want to store value in the array of it's type
        arr_##(*T)[pos]=value;
        //of course, this does not work :)
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
        int      a = 2;
        double   b = 4.2;
        uint64_t c = 123456;

        add_value(0,&a);
        add_value(0,&b);
        add_value(0,&c);

        //add more values
        //do something with arrays
        ....

        return 0;
}
```

Is it possible?

Comment: Why not just have overloaded functions each taking one of the types in question and adding it to the correct array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, name generation is not possible via templates in the way you mean it. You can do as Nick said - just create overloaded functions, or create a template class with static array of the specified type:

```
template <typename T>
struct array_holder
{
    static T * arr[10];
};

template <typename T>
T * array_holder<T>::arr[10];

template <typename T>
void add_value (int pos, T value)
{
    array_holder<T>::arr[pos] = something_you_need;
}
```